# HTML Drop-down how to make the user select first drop-down first before going to next drop-down

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make the user unable to select the second drop-down menu (time) without having selected the first drop-down menu (movie) first?

````
<html>
<body>

<h1>The select element</h1>

<p>The select element is used to create a drop-down list.</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="Movie">Choose a movie:</label>
  <select name="Movie" id="movie">
    <option value="hulk">Hulk</option>
    <option  value="creed">Creed</option>
    <option value="aviator ">Aviator</option>
  </select>

<br><br>

<label for="Time">Choose a time:</label>
  <select name="Time" id="time">
    <option value="12:15">12:15pm</option>
    <option  value="8:00">8:00pm</option>
    <option value="9:00” >9:00pm</option>
  </select>


  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click the "Submit" button and the form-data will be sent to a page on the 
server called "action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

use disabled attribute in select tag.`<select name="Time" id="time" disabled>` This prevents user from clicking on it.

Then check to see if conditions have been met before enabling it with java script

```html
<script>
            var firstDropDown = document.getElementById("movie")

            firstDropDown.addEventListener("click", () => {
                var seconddrop = document.getElementById("time")
                seconddrop.disabled = false
            })
</script>
```

This code will enable the second drop down after user clicks it.

You may want extra condition to be met before you enable the second drop down. For example, have your first option in the drop down be a place holder with no value, check select contains a value before enabling.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).